# Need help adding values within a specific column in my table

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I'm new to R (and programming) looking for help adding the total number of times a specific character appears within one of my columns. All in all there are 175 total rows. Here's a condensed version of my tibble:

| random_code | location |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD20 | San Francisco |
| ABCD30 | Seattle |
| ABCD40 | New York |
| .... | .... |

I'm sure there is a way to calculate the number of times each `random_code` appears in the table but I'm not sure how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)

df |> group_by(random_code) |> mutate(times = n())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - thank you so much! Even learned a new operator, |>

Comment: You can learn more about it in [Forward Pipe Operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html)